# how could calculate $ \int_{C} \frac{1}{\sin(z)} \, dz $ when $C=C(0,1)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

i am trying calculate $$ \int_{C} \frac{1}{\sin(z)} \, dz $$ when $C=C(0,1)$ by complex methods, its said, by residues, some one could help me?

Comment: $z = 0$ is the only singular point inside $C$, compute the residue at $z = 0$.

Comment: Does $C(0,1)$ mean the circle of radius $1$ centered at $0$? $\qquad$

Comment: yes @MichaelHardy

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin (z)=0$ if and only if $z=\pi k, \  k\in \Bbb{Z}$. At $C=C(0,1)$ you have a single pole at $z=0$. To calculate the residue at $z=0$, notice that the only term with a negative power of $z$ in the Laurent's series expansion of $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin z}$ is $\frac{1}{z}$, so the residue at $z=0$ is $1$. Then, by the Residue Theorem, you get

$$\int_{C(0,1)}\frac{1}{\sin z}dz=2\pi i\ Res(\frac{1}{\sin z},0)=2\pi i$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Write the cosecant as

$$\csc(z)=\frac{1}{z\left(1+O(z^2)\right)}=\frac1z+O(z)$$